# Do not "line break" the arrow when using btn-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to do not allow the arrow to go to another line? This will happens if the screen did not have enough space, see the image:

[image]

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/dnooz5ss/)

CODE:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="shrink">COLUMN 1</th>
            <th class="shrink">COLUMN 2</th>
            <th class="expand">COLUMN 3</th>
            <th class="expand">COLUMN 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block dropdown-toggle text-left" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">Descrition of the item <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></span>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Option 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Some info here</td>
            <td>Some more here</td>
            <td>And here too</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block dropdown-toggle text-left" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">Descrition of the i asd adasdasdasdasdtem <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></span>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Option 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Some info here</td>
            <td>Some more here</td>
            <td>And here too</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block dropdown-toggle text-left" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">No item <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></span>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Option 0</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Some info here again</td>
            <td>yay more info here too</td>
            <td>ok, enough info now, that is enough</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Tried some `white-space: nowrap;` but could not get the desired result. Any help will be great. The arrow must be in the right side, always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of floating the carets right, float the text left.

```
<span class="pull-left">Description... </span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dnooz5ss/7)**

Comment: yes, but how can I put the arrow in the right corner?

Answer (score 1):

`span.pull-right` floats the `i.fa-caret-down` to the right *after* your “Description of the item”, which means it’s placed on the next line. Try putting the float *before* the description. For example:

```
<span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block dropdown-toggle text-left"
      data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
  Description of the item
</span>
```

[Sample, fixing the first caret](http://jsfiddle.net/dnooz5ss/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `white-space: nowrap` property will not effect the dropdown icon as it's in a different flow due to the `float: right;` applied to it by the class `.pull-right`.

What you're describing sounds as though you want to set a `position: absolute` against the icon. This *does* fix the issue of the icon not being effected by the text, but it raises a further question of, how do you want to resolve too much text in a button which isn't sufficiently big?

As far as I can see, the only way to resolve this would be to also apply an `overflow: hidden` property to the buttons, to force the spacing to the right where the icon sits to be empty, and to apply an ellipsis on the text if any overflow does occur. You can see the combination of these selectors in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnooz5ss/5/), I have forced the buttons to be smaller purely to demonstrate how this would work when they are forced to consume a space smaller that you would otherwise like:

```
.btn {
    white-space: no-wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.fixed-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}
```